# Setting a specified number of rows in each column and block of elements to zero

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

Is there any easy way to set a specified number of rows `k` in nth column to zero ? Its a bit tricky question to explain so I guess its best to look at the example. 
Lets say I have:

```
A =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
10    11    12
13    14    15
16    17    18
```

I wish to set rows, like this: `[row1 col1] = 0; [row2 col1] = 0`, and then `[row3 col2]= 0; row4 col2]= 0` and so on, so my output is:

```
k = 2
B =

 0     2     3
 0     5     6
 7     0     9
10     0    12
13    14     0
16    17     0
```

Do you have any suggestions/solutions how this could be solved with a `for` loop, or maybe there is another way?

and how this solution could be extend further to something like this: 
     A =

```
  1     2     3     1    2     3
  4     5     6     4    5     6
  7     8     9     7    8     9
 10    11    12    10    11    12
 13    14    15    13    14    15
 16    17    18    16    17    18

B =

 0     0     3     1    2     3
 0     0     6     4    5     6
 7     8     0     0    8     9
10    11     0     0    3     1
13    14    15    13    0     0
16    17    18    16    0     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach -

```
k = 2;

row1 = 1:size(A,1)
col1 = ceil([1:size(A,1)]./k)
A(sub2ind(size(A),row1,col1))=0
```

For the edited question, use `kron` like this -

```
k = 2;

a1 = eye(size(A)./k);
b1 = ones(k,k);
A(logical(kron(a1,b1)))=0
```

Comment: @rayryeng Very similar indeed!

Comment: @Divakar this worked perfectly for me and I added another question about its extension.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a problem.  We can figure out **exactly** which rows and columns you want to set to `0` based on this value `k`, then use `sub2ind` to get a single index to access into your matrix.  This will be in column-major format.  Then you can use this and set all of your values to zero.  Here is an example.  We need to know the `width` and `height` of your matrix first before we do this:

```
rows = [row1 row2 row3];
cols = [col1 col2 col3];

%// Get column major indices
ind = sub2ind([height width], rows, cols);

%// Set the values in this matrix to 0.
B(ind) = 0;
```

Now with your example, we need to access all of the rows.  However, for the columns, we need to access `k` elements in each column and ensuring they don't overlap.  As such, we can do it like so:

```
k = 2;
B = reshape(1:18, 6, 3).';
rows = 1 : 6;
cols = ceil(rows / k);
ind = sub2ind([rows cols], rows, cols);
B(ind) = 0;
```

You would thus get:

```
B =

 0     2     3
 0     5     6
 7     0     9
10     0    12
13    14     0
16    17     0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is executable in matlab, and does what you want:

```
% Create A-matrix
A = reshape(1:18,6,3)
% Set specified datapoints to zero
A([1,2],[1,1]) = 0
```

Alternatively, you can set each element separately

```
A(1,1) = 0
A(1,2) = 0
```

And the most general way, with *k* and *n*:

```
A([1:k],n) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For first question:

```
A(mod(0:numel(A)-1, size(A,1)+k) < k) = 0;
```

For second question, including first question as a particular case:

```
c = repmat({ones(k,size(B,2)/size(B,1)*k)}, size(B,1)/k, 1);
B = B.*~blkdiag(c{:})
```